# selectively extracting fields from a delimited file through the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

If i have a delimited file such as;

```
A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|E=5|F=6
```

and I want to extract certain fields and print them on one line using only standard unix tools (i.e grep,awk,cut). How could I do this?

The text fields may not always be in the same order and there may be more on one line than on another. I want to be able to select fields based on the start of them.

So a query on the above for A= and C= should ouput the following as a single line;

```
A=1 C=2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an awk version that supports specifying RS as a regular expression, e.g. gawk or mawk:

```
echo 'A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|E=5|F=6' | 
  awk -v RS='[|\n]' -v ORS=' ' -v pat='(A|C)=' '$0 ~ pat'; echo
```

Or if you want to avoid the echo at the end:

```
echo 'A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|E=5|F=6' | 
  awk -v RS='[|\n]' -v ORS=' ' -v pat='(A|C)=' '$0 ~ pat; END { printf "\n" }'
```

My favorite:

```
echo 'A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|E=5|F=6' | 
  awk '$0 ~ pat' RS='[|\n]' ORS=' ' pat='(A|C)='; echo
```

Output:

```
A=1 C=3
```

#### Edit

Bugfix, newlines should also be considered record separators.

Comment: @user1977952 Try it with `pat='(A|F)='` and see if it still does what you want as it will add a blank line in that case. Add `{sub(/\n/,"")}` before the test on $0 or `{sub(/\n/,"");print}` after it.

Comment: @EdMorton: I see your point, I've updated the answer to use regex RS, limiting the solution to gawk or mawk (maybe other awk versions?).

Answer (score 0):

does this fit your needs?

```
kent$  echo "A=1|B=2|C=3|D=4|E=5|F=6"|grep -Po "(?<=\||^)(A=|C=)[^|]*"
A=1
C=3
```

if you want it in single line, pipe it to `tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately It didn't 100% meet my needs as it would print the whole output on one line. 

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user1977952 you want it to be printed in one line, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/[A|C]\=/)printf $i" "}}'
```

also you can use perl:

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/[A|C]=\d+/g;END{print "@a"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

using sed

`sed -re 's/(A=[0-9]+)(.*)(C=[0-9]+)(.*)/\1 \3/' temp.txt`

Output

`A=1 C=3`